# Are you supposed to be able to beat LIMBO without dying?

Tags: limbo

Can you beat *LIMBO* without dying without any *a priori* knowledge?  Obviously, if you know the proper path you can (there's even an achievement for it; though even that spots you 4-5 deaths).  Some of the traps are obvious (bear traps, trip-wires), but others seem impenetrable without hitting them once and learning via dying.  Sure, death is cheap in the game, but it makes question if I'm just not looking hard enough.

Fighting the three dart-shooters makes me question this the most.

Comment: I'd say there is pretty much zero possibility of anyone completing this game without prior knowledge. Some bits even purposefully trick you and go against things you've previously learnt. For example just before the 3 dart shooters there is a piston type thing where standing on the plate in the middle is safe, followed by an identical setup but standing on the plate triggers the piston and squashes you.

Answer (score 19):

LIMBO is a game of trial and error, it is expected of you to die until you "solve" some of the levels.

While some levels give hints where danger awaits, it'll rarely straightaway tell you "if you step here you'll die", these will only serve in retrospect, letting you know what gives away what killed you last time, allowing you to prepare better for your next try.

The achievement/trophy for completing the game without dying is aimed for players playing through the game a second time, encouraging them to memorize the stages.

Comment: Wondering what the downvote was for. Care to explain so I can improve my answer?

Comment: +1 for "rarely straight-away tells you ... ".  The game is a b*st*rd and tries its best to kill you at every opportunity.  I don't think it's possible to complete it without dying, given no _priori_